# Items line up in Chrome on PC but not in Chrome on cell phone

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, text-align

I have a confirmation checkbox div within a form on my website.

Within the div, I have the actual checkbox, and the label.

The items seem to line up nicely on my PC, but when I check the page on my cell phone, they are not lined up properly.

I checked both devices in same browser (Chrome).

I can't seem to line them up on the cell version at all.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<title>Align Test</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/alignment.test.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="page_Container">

<div class="center_Wrapper">

<div class="agree_to_Information_Wrap"><input type="checkbox" class="agree_to_Info_Checkbox" 
value="Yes" required><a class="agree_to_Information_Text">I Agree to all of the above 
information.</a></div>

</div>

</div>   

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body{

margin: 0px;
display: flex;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;

}

.page_Container {

width: 100%;
max-width: 1080px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;

}

.agree_to_Information_Wrap {

width: 100%;
height: 20px;
background-color: #000000;
padding: 5px;

}

.agree_to_Information_Checkbox {

}

.agree_to_Information_Text {

margin-left: 10px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;
color: #ffffff;

}
```

Comment: Use your Chrome Inspector to find out what's going on. Usually with these things the font size is increased for smaller screens so that will cause boxes to often expand outside of their expected containers

Comment: @Martin I gave that a look. It doesn't appear that is the particular issue. :/ I'm stumped.